# How to examine implicit/rich conversions and implemented traits in the REPL

Tags: scala

Some things in Scala seems opaque to me such as the following when `to` is not a member function of `Int`:

```
1.to(4)
```

Can I examine what behavior caused this (an implicit conversion or trait or other) without consulting the language reference? And that too in the [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop)?

If the REPL can't help, is there some friendly alternative?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With Scala 2.9:

```
  ~/code/scala scala -Xprint:typer -e "1 to 4"
[[syntax trees at end of typer]]// Scala source: scalacmd4469348504265784881.scala
package <empty> {
  final object Main extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object Main = {
      Main.super.this();
      ()
    };
    def main(argv: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val args: Array[String] = argv;
      {
        final class $anon extends scala.AnyRef {
          def this(): anonymous class $anon = {
            $anon.super.this();
            ()
          };
          scala.this.Predef.intWrapper(1).to(4)
        };
        {
          new $anon();
          ()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With Scala 2.10 or 2.11:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe
import reflect.runtime.universe

scala> val tree = universe.reify(1 to 4).tree
tree: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = Predef.intWrapper(1).to(4)

scala> universe.showRaw(tree)
res0: String = Apply(Select(Apply(Select(Ident(scala.Predef), newTermName("intWrapper")), List(Literal(Constant(1)))), newTermName("to")), List(Literal(Constant(4))))

scala> universe.show(tree)
res1: String = Predef.intWrapper(1).to(4)
```

Comment: See also `:implicits -v` on REPL.