# Find used implicits in the Scala REPL

Tags: scala, scalaz

I often find a neat solution to a problem by using Scalaz pimps. Usually the solution works like

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
foobar frobnicate quux
// magic
```

Now, I would like to be able to see what implicits I have actually used to add to my `Foobar` a frobnicate method. In this way I can make a more refined import and learn something new about the tool I have implicitly used.

> Is there some way to find out what implicit conversions the compiler actually used to compile some expression?

Comment: Not exactly what you wanted but you can enlist all implicits in the current scope with `:implicits`

Comment: I know, but the problem is that if I import Scalaz._ I get *a lot* of implicits and it is just not practical to browse them all...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179415/is-there-a-systematic-way-to-discover-which-implicit-defs-are-in-scope-and-whic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999664/how-to-examine-implicit-rich-conversions-and-implemented-traits-in-the-repl/10001117#10001117

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scala plugin for eclipse shows implicits used. A small icon appears at to the left of the line where it is used. I think Intellij has a similar feature.

Comment: Nice, but I am noit using an IDE, and I don't know if it is worth the hassle of configuring and learning one for just this...

Comment: actually all you need to do is download and extract it: http://typesafe.com/stack/scala_ide_download

Comment: I have tried, but it crashes when I try to change workspace to a given folder containing my Play project

Comment: so choose a different folder, use sbt eclipse and import your project as an "existing eclipse project"

Comment: Cool! :-D Thank you for the hint, it was easier than I thought!

Answer (score 5):

You can also see the fully expanded version of your code using the `-Xprint:typer` option to scalac. In a sbt project, one can add the line

```
scalacOptions += "-Xprint:typer"
```

to `build.sbt` and see the result with the `compile` commmand.

(taken from the answer linked by retronym)