# How can I 'discover' type classes/implicit values in the current scope?

Tags: scala, typeclass, read-eval-print-loop, implicit

I've made use of a few of scala's built-in type classes, and created a few of my own. However, the biggest issue I have with them at the moment is: how do I find type classes available to me? While most of those that I write are small and simple, it would be nice to know if something already exists that does what I'm about to implement!

So, is there a list, somewhere, of all the type classes or implicit values available in the standard library?
Even better, is it possible to somehow (probably within the REPL) generate a list of the implicit values available in the current scope?

Comment: Only one implicit is resolved, otherwise the compiler would raise an error. In macro you can check and get the matching macro.

Comment: I understand that. I don't want an implicit for some specific case; I want to know what _all_ of the possible implicits available to me are.

Comment: Don't think that possible. What would be the point?

Comment: Check out Scala Plugin 1.4.x for IntelliJ IDEA 14 & 14.1: http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2015/03/26/what-to-check-out-in-scala-plugin-1-4-x-for-intellij-idea-14-14-1/

Comment: @cchantep Why do you say it would be impossible? When the compiler searches for implicits in some scope, the search is both deterministic and finite. Could a program not follow similar logic as the compiler would here and just print out everything it finds?

There are two points; to know what type classes are already available to me (to use something provided, rather than rewriting the same thing) and to see how a similar type class is implemented, so I can better implement my own. The documentation doesn't seem to provide any easy way to do either of these without knowing of the class first!

Comment: The compiler is doing a lot of complicated thingy that a program is not able to do itself.

Comment: What complicated things? Why is an arbitrary program not able to them? The compiler is itself a program, after all. Certainly, a program that is running wouldn't necessarily be able to inspect itself in this way (depending on the language, etc.), but I wasn't meaning to suggest that the inspections I want to do are within the running program. I effectively wanted to pass my code and a line number to some program and have it give me a list of implicits. That's what my question was asking, and more-or-less what is demonstrated in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a job for a good IDE.

### IntellijIDEA 14+

Check out [Implicits analyser](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2015/03/26/what-to-check-out-in-scala-plugin-1-4-x-for-intellij-idea-14-14-1/) in Scala Plugin 1.4.x. Example usage:

```
def myMethod(implicit a: Int) = {
}
implicit val a: Int = 1
myMethod // click the myMethod and press Ctrl+Shift+P, the "Implicit Parameters" is shown
```

### Eclipse

Check out [Implicit highlighting](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/features/typingviewing/implicit-highlighting/index.html).

### Scala REPL

You can list implicits like this:

```
:implicits -v
```

And investigate their origin like defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999664/how-to-examine-implicit-rich-conversions-and-implemented-traits-in-the-repl):

```
import reflect.runtime.universe
val tree = universe.reify(1 to 4).tree
universe.showRaw(tree)
universe.show(tree)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for from the REPL, but how do you access the analyser in IntelliJ? I tried searching for a command relating to implicits, but none of those available to me match the screenshot in that link you provided.